# sql statement to select all from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

lists table

```
id user_id list_name
1  1       test
2  1       test2
```

items table

```
id list_id item_name price_item item_checked
1  1       apple     2          0
2  2       orange    2          0
```

result should be

```
id item_name price_item item_checked
1  Apple     2           0
```

How would i accomplish to select all from list 1

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`, `WHERE`.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear but I will try my best to answer it.

To get the results you have posted:

```
select *
from Items_Table
```

Title says select all from a different table. I assume lists is the first table and items is the "different" table you are referring to.

```
Select Items.*
from Lists_Table Lists
left join Items_Table Items on Items.list_id = Lists.id
```

Now, lets assume you were looking for specific items, say where Id is 1 in the lists table. Then you would have the following:

```
Select Items.*
from Lists_Table Lists
left join Items_Table Items on Items.list_id = Lists.id
where Lists.id = 1
```

You can replace Lists.id in the where statement with any other column and set it equal to value you are looking for.

I hope this was helpful. Please try to be a bit more clear about what you are looking for!

Good Luck!

---

Comment: It's a fairly safe bet that the `JOIN` condition should be `items.list_id = lists.id`

Comment: Thanks @Nick. I made the appropriate changes.